# How to check if gps i turned on or not programmatically in android version 4.4 and above?

Tags: java, android, gps, android-4.4-kitkat

I have tried searching for answers online but they seemed to work only for android versions 4.0 and below

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating what you tried and explain, in detail, what you mean by "they seemed to work only for android versions 4.0 and below".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context) {
    int locationMode = 0;
    String locationProviders;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
        try {
            locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

        } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;

    }else{
        locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders);
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks very much It worked like a charm!

Comment: This code is deprecated. can you please suggest alternative code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

> This class provides access to the system location services. These services allow applications to obtain periodic updates of the device's geographical location, or to fire an application-specified Intent when the device enters the proximity of a given geographical location.

Here is a code snippet for what you are looking for

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
```

This has been tested from Android 4.4 and above versions.But Doesn't work for 8.0.

Comment: wgat to do for 8.0 and above?

Comment: this works fine on 8.0 and above.